# how to dispatch actions outside React Compoenent

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

ClickCell and Cell these two functions are outside React Component "Galleries". From the props of this component, I want to access fillGallery action. But I dont know how to do this. is it possible to execute or Dispatch Action outside React Component?

```
const clickCell = (columnName,row_id,store) => {
                    console.log('columnName', columnName)
                    if (columnName.name !== 'email') {

                        if (row_id == localStorage.getItem('updategalleryId')) {
                            $("#Add_gallery_Modal").load("onclick", function () {
                                $("#Add_gallery_Modal").modal("show");
                            });                                  
                        } else {
                            updateIdlocal = null;
                        }
                    }
                }


const Cell = ({row, column, value, ...restProps }) => {
                    const content = column.name === "main_image" ? <img alt="img" className="artwork-iconImg" src={value} /> : value;
                    console.log('column -> value', column.name + "->" + value)
                         return <Table.Cell {...restProps} data-toggle="modal" onClick={() => clickCell(column,row.id,store)}>{content}</Table.Cell>;
                };

class Gallaries extends React.PureComponent {
                    constructor(props) {
                        super(props);
                      }
                }
                const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
                    return {
                        getgallery: state.getgallery,
                        FillData: state.fillGallery,
                        addgallery: state.addGallery,
                        galleryupdate: state.updateGallery
                    };
                }

                const formWrapped = reduxForm({
                    form: 'Gallaries',
                    //validate
                })(multilanguage(Gallaries));

                export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchGallery, AddGallery, fillGallery, updateGallery })(formWrapped);


actions.js

export const fillGallery = (formValues) => async dispatch => {
            const response = await jsonPlaceholder.post('/fill-gallery', formValues, SetAuthoriztoken());
            dispatch({ type: FILL_GALLERY, payload: response.data })
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

You have save the ref of store globally and dispatch action from store reference

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer)
// set global store ref
let storeRef = store;

// disptach action
storeRef.dispatch({type: FILL_GALLERY, payload: {}})
```